# Is public keyword for main class (where main() method exist) mandatory?

Tags: java, public

```
// main class
class prac_1_3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Practical 3");
    }
}
```

I have seen it on many websites and heard that the main class should be a public modifier.

So, to confirm that I ran this above code without a public modifier and it ran successfully.

I want to know about this from you. please explain me that, in which situation a public modifier is required in terms of only main class ( i know the basics about public modifiers but I am confused with the main class file).

with public keyword and without public keyword it executed successfully.

Comment: On the class, no. On the method, yes.

Comment: "*I have seen it on many websites and heard that the main class should be a public modifier.*" that is incorrect as your code proves. From curiosity could you point out some sources which made you think so? Maybe they meant `public` as visibility modifier *of `main` method*, not of class *holding* `main` method?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that on the *class* (not the method)

> with public keyword and without public keyword it executed successfully.

That is your answer. `public` is not needed on the class, only on the method.